# Error while trying to implement Google Play Games functionality

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-play-games

I am in the beginning phases of getting Play Games implemented with my program. About [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin) in the Android Dev website.

The app is crashing immediately upon starting and I am not sure why, I looked through the full stacktrace on nothing jumps out at me telling me where to start with this issue.

Here is the stacktrace:

> 04-19 20:40:52.457: E/AndroidRuntime(4790): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   04-19 20:40:52.457: E/AndroidRuntime(4790): Process:
>   --com.cs407project.cardgameswithfriends, PID: 4790 04-19 20:40:52.457: E/AndroidRuntime(4790): java.lang.IllegalStateException: A fatal
>   developer error has occurred. Check the logs for further information.
>   04-19 20:40:52.457: E/AndroidRuntime(4790):   at
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.eh$h.b(Unknown Source) 04-19
>   20:40:52.457: E/AndroidRuntime(4790):     at
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.eh$h.a(Unknown Source) 04-19
>   20:40:52.457: E/AndroidRuntime(4790):     at
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.eh$b.ec(Unknown Source) 04-19
>   20:40:52.457: E/AndroidRuntime(4790):     at
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.eh$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
>   04-19 20:40:52.457: E/AndroidRuntime(4790):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 04-19
>   20:40:52.457: E/AndroidRuntime(4790):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 04-19 20:40:52.457:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(4790):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 04-19
>   20:40:52.457: E/AndroidRuntime(4790):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 04-19
>   20:40:52.457: E/AndroidRuntime(4790):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 04-19 20:40:52.457:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(4790):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   04-19 20:40:52.457: E/AndroidRuntime(4790):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 04-19
>   20:40:52.457: E/AndroidRuntime(4790):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

The error thrown above says to check the logs. Could you include more of the App's logs prior to the exception were thrown- that would contain the ultimate reason for the error.

There are some few steps that are required in order to properly configure your app. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808309/i-cant-initialize-google-play-game-service) (stackoverflow) is a pretty common error where the App Id is not added to the manifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

. The log should probably be rather specific as to what step was missed.